# Android LinerLayout not aligned

Tags: android, android-layout

Why the `TextView` and `Button` aren't aligned? They should since they have same height and there is no gravity enforced. I tried to fix with gravity but didn't work. Is it a bug?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="70sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My test test test test test test test test test test"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="90sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Button 1 Button Button"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="90sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Button 2 Button Button"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="70sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Info"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Layout rendered]

Comment: Use dp for Views, sp for text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:baselineAligned="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the LinearLayout baseline align Here you have a complete explanation http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/10/shifty-baseline-alignment/

Answer (score 0):

yes it a demerit of linear layout...you don;t have too many options....rather use relative layout or...set "android:baselineAligned="false"" as linear layout property or set top-margins for buttons...as i do 
like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="70sp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="My test test test test test test test test test test"
    android:textSize="10sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="90sp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="My Button 1 Button Button"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="90sp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="My Button 2 Button Button"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_width="70sp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="Info"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the linear layout gravity to center vertical:

```
...
android:gravity="center_vertical"
...
```

Hope it helps.